# iOS 13 has broke part of an app using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport and hammerjs

Tags: angular, cordova, mobile, ios13, hammer.js

After updating to iOS 13.x my Angular Apps Swipe gesture is no longer working properly to show side menu items.  After updating it fails to to lock the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport leading to undesired behavior.

I am using hammerjs to lock the list from scrollingwhen swipping.  Here is the pseudocode for how I am currently detecting horizontal gestures and animating the buttons appearing:

```
   // using the Hammer.on event
   if (initialDirection === Hammer.DIRECTION_NONE) {
      // no decision on gesture yet made
      if (
        e.distance > DIRECTION_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD &&
        e.direction > Hammer.DIRECTION_NONE
      ) {
        initialDirection = e.direction;
      }
    } else if (
      initialDirection &
      (Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT)
    ) {
         //translate amount user moved and then snap open if the end of the event
      }
```

Versions in use:
- Angular 8.1.1 
- hammerjs 2.0.8 
- @angular/cdk/scrolling 8.2.3
- Cordova 9
- WkWebview

Stackblitz is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsvqzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).  There is a styled text component that normally exists instead of just the text but this is the relevant section.

Comment: Have you tried this ticket [answer](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1084#issuecomment-544220158)?

Comment: Yes I tried the accepted answer and the touch-action answer and neither are working, with touch-action the browser kills scrolling but not translate because I handle that directly. It seems the browser is hijacking horizontal events and treating them as scrolls which it hadn't in the prior version of iOS

Comment: Could you recreate the issue on a stackblitz possibly?

Comment: Yup I can create a stackblitz of it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsvqzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
There is a styled text component that normally sits in instead of just the text but this is the relevant section @Lucho